# What does this "general protection fault" in my console mean, and how do I interpret it?

Tags: debian, kernel

I had a couple of consoles open for other work and when I came back to them they both contained the following:

```
Message from syslogd@Stacey-Windows at Jun 19 09:43:28 ...

kernel:[ 4375.127165] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP 

Message from syslogd@Stacey-Windows at Jun 19 09:43:28 ...
kernel:[ 4375.127311] Stack:

Message from syslogd@Stacey-Windows at Jun 19 09:43:28 ...
kernel:[ 4375.127330] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@Stacey-Windows at Jun 19 09:43:28 ...
kernel:[ 4375.127423] Code: 00 00 89 44 24 24 c7 44 24 30 04 00 00 00 c7 44 24 34 6c 00 00 00 48 89 4c 24 38 e8 e1 fa ff ff 85 c0 78 03 8b 04 24 48 83 c4 48 <c3> 48 83 ec 38 8b 07 48 8b 7f 08 48 89 54 24 24 ba 30 00 00 00
```

This looks like an exception has been thrown somewhere in my os, I gather it's a stacktrace of some kind. The code looks like a hexdump of something. What exactly is this and is there anything I can do with this information to know exactly what went wrong/where? What is it used for?

EDIT:

I just took a look at `/var/log/messages` and got this:

```
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127227] 
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127241] Pid: 4462, comm: vivado Tainted: G           O 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.2.51-1 innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127247] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa02a0876>]  [<ffffffffa02a0876>] vboxCallCreate+0x7e/0x7f [vboxsf]
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127259] RSP: 0018:ffff88019ab47be0  EFLAGS: 00010292
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127263] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88019ab47c7c RCX: 00000000000018fb
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127267] RDX: 0000000000000041 RSI: ffff88007131f540 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127271] RBP: ffff88019a974000 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 00000000ffffffff
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127275] R10: ffffffff81600000 R11: ffffffff81600000 R12: ffff88019ab47e78
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127279] R13: ffff88012c06c500 R14: ffff88019b84a180 R15: ffff88012c06f300
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127283] FS:  00007f76b998d700(0000) GS:ffff8801a2c00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127288] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127291] CR2: 0000000731c95000 CR3: 000000019860a000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127298] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127303] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127307] Process vivado (pid: 4462, threadinfo ffff88019ab46000, task ffff880198dd0930)
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127314]  33d59c00137905a4 33d59c00137905a5 33d59c00137905a5 001041ed137905a5
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127320]  000003e800000002 00000002000003e8 00e6017800000801 0000000000000000
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127325]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127338]  [<ffffffffa029f009>] ? sf_inode_revalidate+0x78/0xae [vboxsf]
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127346]  [<ffffffff8110a5c7>] ? dput+0x27/0xee
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127352]  [<ffffffff8110b5ac>] ? __d_lookup+0x3e/0xce
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127358]  [<ffffffff8110252c>] ? path_to_nameidata+0x19/0x3a
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127364]  [<ffffffffa029f055>] ? sf_dentry_revalidate+0x16/0x20 [vboxsf]
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127370]  [<ffffffff81103223>] ? walk_component+0x28f/0x406
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127376]  [<ffffffff81104fe2>] ? do_last+0x108/0x58d
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127381]  [<ffffffff81105a5f>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127386]  [<ffffffff81105d8d>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127393]  [<ffffffff8134deec>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127400]  [<ffffffff811b41f9>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127407]  [<ffffffff8110eb13>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127413]  [<ffffffff810f9d59>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127419]  [<ffffffff81354212>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127455]  RSP <ffff88019ab47be0>
Jun 19 09:43:28 Stacey-Windows kernel: [ 4375.127551] ---[ end trace 7aaadecc7e737e8f ]---
```

So there's a vivado in there - it's one of the applications I use, and there's a vbox in there. I'm running debian (and vivado) in virtualbox.

Is this something I should be worried about? Is this something I can fix?

Linux details: Debian Wheezy 7.0 64-bit

Comment: Did your computer go to sleep while you were away and when you came back you woke it to find that in the virtual machine?

Comment: I was using it all the time, I just wasn't using the consoles. I did notice that one of my vivado windows had disappeared.

Comment: Ahh, well, then I've nothing further to offer except - @slm - any ideas? He's usually pretty good with virtual stuff.

Comment: You might clip that part of the log and save it, see if this issue occurs again, perhaps there are similarities.  It may have been a one-off, cosmic-rays, bad-karma, cold-coffee... no telling what might have caused it.  Recover (if you can) and continue.  Kind of like that rattle you tell your mechanic about, unless we can repeat it, it's very difficult to troubleshoot. {Grin} Basically... make it do that again! (or not... your call)